# Need complete picture of virtual address space

Tags: windows, assembly, linux-kernel, driver, kernel

This image gives a good picture about Virtual Address space. But it only says half of the story. It only gives complete picture of User Address space ie.. lower 50% (or 75% in some cases).

What about the rest  50% (or 25%) which is occupied by the kernel. I know kernel also has so many different things like kernel modules , device drivers, core kernel itself. There must be some kind of layout right?

What is its layout? If you say its Operating System dependent. I would say, there are two major operating systems Windows & Linux. Please give answer for any one these.

[alt text http://img690.imageshack.us/img690/2543/virtualadressspace.gif](http://img690.imageshack.us/img690/2543/virtualadressspace.gif)

Comment: I've got bad news for you.  What you want can't be provided.  It not only depends on operating system, but also on which version of the operating system is in use.  Also, your user address space diagram is also incomplete and depends a lot on which compiler you're using and what version of it is there.

Comment: Only two major operating systems?

Comment: @JUST MY correct OPINION: `Also, your user address space diagram is also incomplete `: How come? I always thought this is complete. & how come this is dependent on the compiler? I thought this only depends on Operating system.

Comment: Operating systems don't know (or much care) what you're using your memory for within security limits.  Your compiler's runtime cares.  If the OS is given the information for how much space to allocate and where to enter upon starting, it doesn't much care about the rest.  Thus the user-space layout will differ between, say, C++ and Dylan (beginning with stack frames).  Also, if you have garbage collection in your runtime that will change layouts; different garbage collection techniques give you different layouts.  Even the layout between two C++ compilers will be different in places.

Comment: @Carl: Only two major operating systems as long as you completely ignore the multi-billion dollar mainframe industry.  Or the multi-billion dollar mobile systems industry.  Or the multi-billion dollar embedded systems industry.  Or the multi-billion dollar secure system industry.  Or the...

Comment: There is also a clue in your diagram referring to virtual address space. Each user space process runs in its own address space, the kernel however runs in actual physical address space. If you actually look at the addresses you may even see overlap (not that it matters as the virtual address will map to a non-clashing physical address if it's in memory at all).

Comment: @ JUST MY correct OPINION: I'm not fully convinced. Compiler (linker) generates the binary image file. Which is then loaded into memory by loader, which is integral part of the OS. Its the loader that draws this layout. Then how come its compiler dependent and not OS dependent?

Comment: And on sparc userland and kernel live in separate address spaces.

Comment: @Nikolai N Fetissov: Kindly can you give me a reference that supports your point. I'm little surprised! I want to read it for myself. :)

Comment: @claws, here - http://www.sparc.org/standards/SPARCV9.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Memory Layout of Windows Kernel. Picture taken from [Reversing: Secrets of Reverse Engineering](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0764574817)

[alt text http://img821.imageshack.us/img821/1525/windowskernelmemorylayo.jpg](http://img821.imageshack.us/img821/1525/windowskernelmemorylayo.jpg)

Comment: The link is dead

Answer (score 2):

I've got even worse news for you, there's also a feature to explicitly randomize kernel address layouts by the OS as a security feature. This is on by default in most recent Windows, OpenBSD as well as being an option for Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Like users said here, your picture is incomplete. It tends to look something specific to single-threaded OS. In particular there may be hundreds of threads within the process (hence - sharing the same address space), everyone with its own stack.

Also, I believe the actual picture of the address space may vary strongly depending on OS version and some subtle changes.

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely clear from your question or the image, but with the 'System Address Space' you probably mean the area between 2GB-4GB.  This indeed takes up half of the theoretical 4GB space, but there is a valid reason for it.

Normally with 32-bits you can address 4 GB of memory (2^32=4294967296) so it would seem logical to have 4 GB of address space, not 2 GB.  The reason for this is the following:
Suppose you have 2 pointers, like this in C/C++:

```
char *ptr1;
char *ptr2;
```

I now want to know what the difference is between the two pointers, like this:

```
offset = ptr2 - ptr1;
```

What should be the data type of 'offset'?
If we don't know whether ptr1 comes before ptr2 or vice versa, the offset can be positive or negative.  Now if both ptr1 or ptr2 are between the range 0 - 2GB, then the offset is always between -2147483648 and +2147483647, which fits exactly in a 4 byte signed integer.

However, if ptr1 and ptr2 would be able to access the full 4 GB address space, offset would be between -4294967296 and +4294967295 which doesn't fit in a 4 byte signed integer anymore.

If you are sure that you are never doing this kind of calculations in your application, or you are sure that if you subtract 2 pointers that they will be never more apart than 2 GB (or your vectors are always smaller than 2 GB), you can tell the linker (Windows, Visual Studio) that your application is LARGEADDRESSAWARE.  This linker flag sets a bit in the executable, and if a 32-bit Windows is booted correctly (on XP you had to boot with the /3GB) flag, Windows gave you 3GB instead of 2GB (only for the LARGEADDRESSAWARE executables).
The remaining 1GB is still used for operating system data structures (but I have no details about them).

If you are running a 64-bit Windows, then things get even more interesting, because LARGEADDRESSAWARE executables will then get 4GB of memory.  Apparently, the operating system data structures are now stored somewhere in the 64-bit address space, outside the 4GB used by the application.

Hope this clarifies a bit.